# "VS 2013 Color Theme Editor" Shortcut to themes

Tags: plugins, visual-studio-2013, themes

I would like to attach a keyboard shortcut to switch themes in Visual Studio 2013.

Example: Ctrl+1 would change to Light theme, Ctrl+2, to Dark theme, etc.
I also have Visual Commander installed, so if there's a macro out there, I would like to know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try macros.

alt + t 
o 
alt + c 
[d/l/b] (dark/light/blue) 
enter

Worth a try
This is my scribt for autohotkey(http://www.autohotkey.com/)

^!1::
    KeyWait 1
    KeyWait ^
    KeyWait !
    Send, !t
    Send, o
    Send, !c
    Send, l
    Send {Enter}
Return

^!1:: s the hotkey I assigned it to :P

Comment: never though of using external programs for this, thanks!